# Checking a checkbox using Ruby/Watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I'm trying to automate pulling some data requests from LinkedIn each Friday, but I need to check specific checkboxes to request only relevant data.

After going through the documentation and multiple posts I still cannot seem to solve this issue.

The specific request page is under LinkedIn's privacy page where you request to download all of your data.

Here's the checkbox line of code:

```
browser.checkbox(id: 'file_group_INVITATIONS').set(true)
```

I've also tried setting it to false, using the value rather than id as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set the checkbox will give the error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError : unknown error: Element
>   <input type="checkbox" name="requestedFiles[]"
>   id="file_group_INVITATIONS" value="INVITATIONS"> is not clickable at
>   point (420, 481). Other element would receive the click: <label
>   for="file_group_INVITATIONS">...</label>

LinkedIn wanted to style their checkbox, so they actually place a label on top of the actual checkbox element. As a user, when you are clicking the "checkbox", you are actually clicking the label element. This is what the error message is referring to when it talks about another element receiving the click.

You can do the same in Watir. The label is properly associated with the checkbox, which allows you to simply do:

```
browser.checkbox(id: 'file_group_INVITATIONS').label.click
```

Or more directly:

```
browser.label(:for => 'file_group_INVITATIONS').click
```

Comment: That makes way more sense. Thank you for your help, Justin!

Comment: Hi, WATIR is not rescuing this error even after Firefox recently has given the exception for this `ElementClickInterceptedError` I understand there are some permanent overlay like given by OP would not disappear over the period of time, but it's not the case for all, some of them are removed quickly and the element become clickable. So WATIR has to rescue this case, let it fail in default time out if it is permanent overlay otherwise let it continue without any problem, what do you say Justin?

Comment: @Rajagopalan is that the problem reported in https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/532?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I am saying.